# A data structure in Perl (retrieved by XML::Simple)

Tags: xml, perl

What this structure in perl means:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'hostname' => {
                      'name' => 'computer'
                      'role' => [
                                  {
                                    'a' => 'bcd',
                                  },
                                ]
                     }
     }
```

I got this using XML::Simple. But what the square brackets means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It means `role` points to an array of values. In your specific example the array only has a single element - a hash ref.

There is some discussion in the [man page for XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple) about controlling how these values are returned. You probably want to look at `KeyAttr` settings.

Comment: Thanks. But although it is an array. I cannot use 'foreach' statement. Also I try to set @temparray = $var1->{'hostname'}->{'role'}. But it still does not work. I just want to get access to each of the hash in the 'role'. Do you know how to pull them out?

Comment: It's a reference to an array, rather than a list. To convert it to a simple list, you would use `@{...}` notation. `my @temparray = @{ $var1->{hostname}->{role} };` I find including the spaces improves readability, but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider ticking my answer if it solved your problem - that's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Yes. But how to tick an answer?

Comment: There should be an outline of a tick symbol to the left of the answer. Click it to mark the answer as 'accepted'

Answer (score 0):

The '[]' characters begin and end an array.  The '{}' symbols are for a hash.  In this case 'role' is an array of hashes.  It only had one item and with two items would have looked like:

```
'role' => [
              {
                  'a' => 'bcd',
              },
              {
                  'e' => 'fgh',
              },
          ]
```

Comment: Thanks. But although it is an array. I cannot use 'foreach' statement. Also I try to set @temparray = $var1->{'hostname'}->{'role'}. But it still does not work. I just want to get access to each of the hash in the 'role'. Do you know how to pull them out? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can.  First `foreach my $href (@{$VAR1->{hostname}->{role}})`, then `foreach my $key (keys %{$href})` and finally `print "key=$key value=$href->{$key}.\n";`.